# request parameters from a jsp in java without using servlets

Tags: java, forms, jsp, parameters, request

I want to request parameters in a java file from a jsp without using servlets. Does anyone know how to do this? I believe its something to do with setting an attribute but I'm new to java so its all a learning game from me. I want to send the lotsize and bedrooms parameters to the java file. My jsp file is shown below and i need to know what to put in my java file in order to retrieve these parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "without using servlets"?

Comment: @Hulk I want to just use java class to get the parameters. I do not want to use a servlet because I will be using sockets and they don't go well togeher

Comment: To use JSP you need a web server. And if you have webserver you can go with servlets or REST API (which is also kind of servlets).

Comment: Where and how is your `HouseWS` class running? If you need to call it from your JSP, then it will be running in the container anyway.

Comment: jsp are also servlets

Comment: Why duplicating question from few minutes ago ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111199/request-parameters-from-jsp-in-java-without-using-servlets/54111303#54111303

Comment: @user7294900 Because I still need an answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want this indeed, you should use HTML instead to JSP. For your question, I'm not sure, but I guess, because of the socket is based on the TCP protocol, so you can use a browser as a socket client, use GET or POST request to the socket server, you can enter the socket server's address in browser or submit an HTML form, the socket receives the request and response headers and HTML body to the browser.